# Define a dataframe column such as each row is equal to itself times the previous one

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fine the most pythonic way to define a dataframe column such as each row is equal to itself times the previous row value: row[i] = row[i] * row [i-1] (as a result, the first row stays identical)

```
import pandas as pd

list = [1,2,3]

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['a'] = list

   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

I am expecting the function to output:

   a
0  1 (stays identical)
1  2 (2*1)
2  6 (3*2)
```

Is this possible without using iterrows()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `shift()` and `fillna()`:

```
df['a']=df['a']*df['a'].shift(1).fillna(df['a'])
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    a 
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   6.0
```

If needed use `astype()` method:

```
df['a']=df['a'].astype(int)
```

Output of above code:

```
    a
0   1
1   2
2   6
```

Comment: Try cumprod should be simpler

Comment: And he wants 1st element to be identical aren't you filling the 1st element by 1?

Comment: @Nk03 fixed it..In the example case it is 1 so I filled it with 1...Btw Thnx for noticing **:)**